# Advice for Setting Up Rails Sites for Prototyping

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and have just signed up with LunarPages as my webhosting company.  To start, I want to write some test applications and get them uploaded and running on my website just to understand how things work.  However, I don't want anyone looking at what I'm working on as I learn.  Does anyone have any advice as to how I should structure my pages and sites in such a way that I can keep them hidden until I'm ready to go live?  Can I easily do something like this?

www.mysite.com  <- everyone can see
www.mysite.com/testapplication1  <- no one can see for now
www.mysite.com/testapplication2  <- no one can see for now

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question.  I'm just starting out.  By the way, I have heard of Heroku but I've already paid for this webhosting service so I'd like to get my money's worth, at least until my subscription is up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if LunarPages offers the level of configurability that is required to run rails apps from sub-directories. I'd use subdomains (testapp1.mysite.com, testapp2.mysite.com) and then use appropriate access control (could be htaccess, HTTP BASIC AUTH in your app, or something more complex like authlogic)